# Make toggle function work only for the box that is clicked open and not all boxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, toggleclass

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.box').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $btn = $(this);
            $btn.toggleClass('opened');

            var heights = $btn.hasClass('opened') ? 300 : 100;
            $(this).stop().animate({ height: heights }, 800);
            //$(".sync_store_info_input_holder").toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Using the above code i am able to accomplish what i need but i have a slight problem with the following line:

$(".sync_store_info_input_holder").toggle();

I need that to show only when the .box opens and not when it closes.  I also need it so show only for the box that the user opens.  I have 18 boxes that use the .box class and only ids are unique so the only box the user opens thats when the toggle function should work.

Comment: Post the accompanying markup.

Comment: To determine when to toggle, you could use the same method you used to define `heights`: `$btn.hasClass('opened')`.

Comment: Are you trying to use this [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) or this [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you can use the [showOrHide](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-showOrHide) version of `toggle()`. If not, make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of your code to explain the problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.box').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $btn = $(this);
            $btn.toggleClass('opened');

            // Make whether the box is open a variable for reuse
            var isOpen = $btn.hasClass('opened');
            var heights = isOpen ? 300 : 100;

            // Reuse $btn instead of $(this)
            $btn.stop().animate({ height: heights }, 800);

            // Important change
            $(".sync_store_info_input_holder").toggle(isOpen);
        });
    });
</script>
```

#### Edit

> I also need it so show only for the box that the user opens. I have 18 boxes that use the .box class and only ids are unique so the only box the user opens thats when the toggle function should work.

Do you mean that there is an `.sync_store_info_input_holder` element within each box? If so, you can change the line to

```
$(".sync_store_info_input_holder", this).toggle(isOpen);
```

to select only the element within the `.box` [context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context). If it's outside of the `.box`, you'd have to show the HTML for us to give an example.

Comment: This still shows that div for all other boxes.  I only need the .sync_store div to show for the box that is clicked open and not all others.  I am new to js so very confused about it and +1 for trying!

Comment: @starbucks Can you show us your HTML (the `.box` and `.sync_store_info_input_holder` elements)?